# Cannot change div's height in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="wraptop">
<img id="imgtop" src="imgtop/01.jpg" alt="img">
<div id="divcenter">
...
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#divcenter{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width:50%;
    left:25%;
    top:25px;
}
```

js

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var a = $("#imgtop").height() - 30;
    alert (a);  // 637
    $("#divcenter").css("height", a + "px"); //doesn't work
    var b = $("#divcenter").height(); 
    alert (b);  // doesn't work
});
```

Height of `divcenter` is not changed.
Also, first alert works but the second does not.
Console is empty.

Any idea ?

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to compensate for the shortcomings of your html structure / css by hacking together a fix in javascript, I'd suggest taking a few steps back and try to find a suitable pure css solution

Comment: I tried it with a jsfiddle and it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/xba8k99m/

Comment: @andrew, I'm almost sure there is no pure css solution for adjusting height of an absolutely positioned div as a percent of reletively positioned parent.

Comment: @OdaYukimura, I checked everything again and have no idea why it doesn't work for me. Anyway, you helped me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but if you're trying to make all your divs the same height you should look at flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).load(function() {
var a = $("#imgtop").height() - 30;
alert (a);  // 637
$("#divcenter").css({"height": a }); //doesn't work
var b = $("#divcenter").height(); 
alert (b);  // doesn't work
});
```

Comment: What did you change? Could you explain your answer a little bit?

Comment: I have added {} around css and instead of , used : is is it working?

Comment: You really took the "little bit" quite literally didn't you